# JNLP Launch Error

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a JNLP file that was working fine and it looks like my computer no longer runs it after I upgraded to Java 1.7 (32 bit jdk1.7.0_02)
When I select view details in the **Unable to launch the application** dialog, the launch file appears as random characters and the exception is:

```
MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>] at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

You can see the file here: [Download Trial Version of The Proctinator](http://proctinator.com/dist/demo.html)

It looks like the file is working on other computers running Java 6. Yet the computer I'm having issues with is able to launch other JNLP files just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try listing the verbatim http response as sent to the client.  It is most likely an incorrect MIME-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to validate the launch file using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) before wondering too much about differences between versions.  If the JNLP is invalid, it is anybody's guess as to how a JWS client will interpret it.

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for http://proctinator.com/dist/launch.jnlp

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8
Codebase + href 'http://proctinator.com/ProctinatorDemo.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'http://proctinator.com/dist/launch.jnlp'.
...
```

---

BTW - something in the description that will **not** be detected by JaNeLA.

> The proctinator saves paper by distributing the assignments *trough*
>   eMail and the web.

Should be ..

> The proctinator saves paper by distributing the assignments *through*
>   eMail and the web.

And.. +1 for helping the trees.